# how to get location from gps

Tags: android, gps, location

i'm trying from many days but don't know what is wrong in my code it gives me the same location and never get the updated location from gps i know this question has lot of anwsers and i have tried many solutions but still i'm getting the same thing. please i request you people to look into my code and see where is the mistake any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener  {


long time = 600* 1000; 
long distance = 10; 
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
Location location;
String device_id;
double latitude;
double longitude;
String phoneNo = "+980070000";

@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    System.out.println("alarm receiver....");
    Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    context.startService(service);

    //Start App On device restart
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
    Intent App = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    App.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(App);
    }

   TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   device_id = tm.getDeviceId();  // returns IMEI number  

try {
    LocationManager   locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

 if (isGPSEnabled) {
      if (location == null) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,time,distance, this);
            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
        if (locationManager != null) {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (location != null) {
                 latitude =   location.getLatitude();
                 longitude = location.getLongitude();
                   String Text =  " From GPS: Latitude = " + latitude +" Longitude = " + longitude + " Device Id: " + device_id;

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, Text, null, null);
                    Log.i("Send SMS", "");
                    this.abortBroadcast(); 
                    } 
               }       
 }
              else {
                    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, time,distance, this);
                        Log.d("Network", "Network");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                location.getLatitude();
                                location.getLongitude();

                                String Text =  " From Network: Latitude = " + latitude +" Longitude = " + longitude + " Device Id: " + device_id;

                                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, Text, null, null);
                                Log.i("Send SMS", "");
                                this.abortBroadcast(); 
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }   
} catch (Exception e) {

      Toast.makeText(context, "no connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      e.printStackTrace();
                    }     
 }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    System.out.println("location changed....");
  }

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` gives the last know location when there is no location update from the `LocationManager`. I guess you are always getting location from this always. May be try different location by chaging location if you are using emulator or by physically moving if you have a real device :-/

Comment: i've tried at different locations it always give the same location

Answer (score 0):

When you get location from GPS, it can take some time, because GPS module needs to find satellites. So you need to wait couple or few minutes while GPS module find satellites. If WI-FI location provider available you can get location more quick.

If you are inside a building it can be hard to get a GPS location. It depends on device and device GPS module.

And I don't see logic here:

```
if (location == null) {
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,time,distance, this);
```

Why do you need to check location for null before register GPS provider listener?

Comment: so  this line is useless?